# Python subprocess.Popen: redirect `STDERR` only and keep `STDOUT`

Tags: python, windows, redirect, subprocess

### Setup

I have a little `Runner` program, that prints some info in `sys.stderr` (for logs, unhandled exceptions and etc.) and `sys.stdout` (some usefull info about program, maybe interaction with user or smth):

```py
import sys
import time

for i in range(1, 4):
    sys.stdout.write(f"This is text #{i} to STDOUT\n")
    sys.stderr.write(f"This is text #{i} to STDERR\n")

time.sleep(5)
```

And I have some `Main` program, that starts `Runner` in the **new window** with `subprocess.Popen` and prints it's output:

```py
import subprocess

cmd = "python runner.py"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, # Problem line
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
                       )

proc.wait()
out, err = proc.communicate()
if out:
    print(f"[{out.decode('utf-8')}]")
if err:
    print(f"[{err.decode('utf-8')}]")
```

So the resulting output is:

```
[This is text #1 to STDOUT
This is text #2 to STDOUT 
This is text #3 to STDOUT
]
[This is text #1 to STDERR
This is text #2 to STDERR
This is text #3 to STDERR
]
```

###### Why `Popen`?

I need to run several `Runners` parallely and wait them lately, but `subprocess.check_input` or `subprocess.run` does not allow that (or am I wrong??)

###### Why new window?

I want to see prints separetely for every `Runner` in their personal windows

### What I want

I want to redirect `stderr` **only** and keep `stdout` in opened window, so the `Main` program will only output errors from subprocess:

```
[This is text #1 to STDERR
This is text #2 to STDERR
This is text #3 to STDERR
]
```

That will be very usefull for debugging new `Runner`'s features...

### What I tried

When `subprocess.Popen` has `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` param and `stdout=None` (default), `stdout` is blocking:

- it doesn't show in the `Runner` window
- and `proc.communicate` returns `None`

So the `stdout` prints just disappeared... I tried even pass `sys.stdout` to `stdout=` param (for output not in window, but in current console), but it throws `Bad file descriptor` error:

```
[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kirin\source\repos\python_tests\runner.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.stdout.write(f"This is text #{i} to STDOUT\n")
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1251'>
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
]
```

*(btw, this print was succesfully redirected from `Runner` to `Main`)*

Need help...

Comment: If stuff sent to `sys.stderr` works, have you considered passing `stdout=sys.stderr, stderr=PIPE`?

Comment: Any `stdout=sys.str{in,out,res}` leads to `Bad file descriptor`... Redirect with `stdout=PIPE` works fine, but I don't want to redirect `stdout` at all... That's the point.

Comment: And it fails if you just fail to pass `stdout=ANYTHING` entirely as well, correct?

Comment: Updated previous comment: I can pass `PIPE` sucessfully, but I don't want that. And I can keep `None`, but then output disappears from the `Runner` window...

Comment: Wait, so if you don't pass `stdout` at all (letting it go to the default location), it works, but no output appears in the runner window at all?

Comment: Yes. That's the problem...

Comment: I can't reproduce; when I run `>>> out, err = subprocess.Popen(r'''py -3 -c "import atexit, sys, time; atexit.register(time.sleep, 5); sys.stdout.write('ABC\n'); sys.stderr.write('DEF\n')"''', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()` from an interactive Python 3.10.0 session on Windows 11, the new window appears for five seconds with `ABC` in it, and when `communicate` returns, `out` is `None` and `err` is `DEF` as expected. Seems to work exactly as expected.

Comment: That's strange... I've tried version 3.9 and 3.10.5 on Windows 10, and it still doesn't work... I'll search for problems in my environment (for example, I've set `VirtualTerminalLevel` registry value for enabling ANSI colors, maybe that's the problem), will do some tests, and then I'll come back with results one day (not today, I think). Thanks for research and testing!

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a solution that meets the requirements of the 'What I want' section:**

`main.py`:

```
import subprocess

command = ["python", "runner.py"]
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False, text=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
process.wait()
stderr = process.stderr.read()
print(stderr, end="")
```

`runner.py` contains the code mentioned in the question.

Argument `shell=False` is used to run `python runner.py` directly (i.e. not as a shell command), `text=True` makes `subprocess` open `process.stderr` in text mode (instead of binary mode).

When running this, output from `runner.py` sent to *stdout* appears in the new window while output sent to *stderr* is captured in variable `stderr` (and also printed in `main.py`'s window).

---

If `runner.py`'s output shall be processed right away as it is produced (i.e. without waiting for the process to finish first), the following code may be used:

`main.py`:

```
import subprocess

command = ["python", "runner.py"]
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False, text=True, bufsize=1, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
stderr = ""
while (True):
    line = process.stderr.readline()
    if (line == ""): break # EOF
    stderr += line
    print(line, end="")
```

`runner.py` (modified to illustrate the difference):

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(1, 4):
    sys.stdout.write(f"This is text #{i} to STDOUT\n")
    sys.stderr.write(f"This is text #{i} to STDERR\n")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Argument `bufsize=1` is used here to get line-buffered output from `runner.py`'s *stderr*.

---

Successfully tested on Windows 10 21H2 + Python 3.10.4.